# Is there a Stack Exchange site to ask about PC configurations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site to ask about PC configurations? I didn't find something obvious. I guess you could ask a question about general pc questions in one of the technology groups but it would be kind of out of context..

It would be nice to create one.

By PC configurations I mean, examples:

- someone wants to buy a new pc and assemble it piece by piece
- someone wants to upgrade
- set up different screens and resolutions
- which graphics card to buy

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, that doesn't sounds like a good Stack Exchange site - where answers are supposed to stand the test of time.

A question / answer like that would become obsolete very quickly, the way hardware moves along.

It is also entirely a recommendation site - which tend to not work well.

You can always follow the existing [area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations).

Comment: thanks, area51 seems apppropriate